# change enter key behavior in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery's autocomplete widget and I want the enter key to serve two purposes:

1. If the user hits the enter key when focus is on the search box, it should open a form (regardless of current matches).
2. If the system finds a match **and the user selects it** from the list by pressing enter, it should display a different dialog.

**The problem is I haven't been able to tell events apart, as it seems that when I choose an option from the autocomplete list of matches, the text box retains focus.**

This is where I'm at right now:

**My autocomplete function:**

```
jQuery('#nom_id_busqueda').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {term: encodeURI(request.term)},
            success: function (answer) {
               if (answer.length == 0) {
                  jQuery("#encontrada").hide();
                  jQuery("#no_encontrada").show();
               }
               else {
                  jQuery("#no_encontrada").hide();
                  response(answer);
               }
            },
            error : function(){ alert("Something went wrong."); },
        });
    },
    minLength:2,
    delay:400,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item){
            jQuery("#nom_id_busqueda").val(ui.item.label);
            jQuery("#per_busq").val(ui.item.value);
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#encontrada").show();
        }
    },
});
```

**and my event listener for the keystroke:**

```
jQuery('#nom_id_busqueda').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        if(jQuery("#nom_id_busqueda").is(":focus")) {
            jQuery("#no_encontrada").hide();
            jQuery("#encontrada").hide();
            jQuery("#div_formu_busq").dialog("close");
            jQuery("#div_formu_per").dialog("open");
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Update:
Here's my DOM:

```
<div id="div_formu_busq" class="formu_fs" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_BUSQUEDA_PERSONA');?>">
<form name="formu_busq" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_BUSCAR_EN_EXISTENTES');?></legend>
        <?php echo JText::_("COM_ESCRIBA_EL_NOMBRE_O_EL_NUMERO_DE_IDENTIFICACION_PARA_BUSCAR_EN_EL_SISTEMA").' '. JText::_("COM_ENTER_LO_LLEVA_AL_FORMULARIO") ;?><br>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <label for=nom_id_busqueda><?php echo JText::_("COM_NOMBRE_O_NUMERO_DE_DOCUMENTO");?></label>
            <input type="text" name="nom_id_busqueda" id="nom_id_busqueda" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="per_busq" id="per_busq" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="encontrada" class="buts">
    <fieldset>
        <p><?php echo JText::_("COM_SE_ENCONTRO_UNA_PERSONA_CON_EL_MISMO_NOMBRE_Y_O_IDENTIFICACION");?> <a class="button_fs_a blue_b" onclick="irAPersona()" ><?php echo JText::_('COM_IR_A_PERSONA'); ?></a></p>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="no_encontrada" class="buts">
    <fieldset> 
        <p>
            <?php echo JText::_("COM_NO_SE_ENCONTRARON_RESULTADOS_SIMILARES");?>
            <a class="button_fs_a blue_b" id="m_formu_per" ><?php echo JText::_('COM_AGREGAR_USUARIO'); ?></a>
        </p>
    </fieldset> 
</div>
```

Comment: When either of the two new forms are opened, will you still want the autocomplete to be active? Can you please provide the accompanying HTML so we can get an idea of the DOM structure?

Comment: @DevlshOne: I don't need the autocomplete to be active when either of the two new divs are opened. I intend to use the enter key for opening a new form, unless it's been used for match selection.

Comment: Looks like you found your own solution - nice job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the way! In the event listener I added the `!jQuery(this).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active` condition, so my keystroke listener now looks like this:

```
jQuery('#nom_id_busqueda').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !jQuery( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active){
        if(jQuery("#nom_id_busqueda").is(":focus")) {
            jQuery("#no_encontrada").hide();
            jQuery("#encontrada").hide();
            jQuery("#div_formu_busq").dialog("close");
            jQuery("#div_formu_per").dialog("open");
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks anyway.

**Edit:**
I tried using keyup instead of keydown, but it seems it somehow breaks the behavior I worked so hard to get.

**Warning:**
For this to work you need to place the `keydown(...)` code so that it gets executed before the `autocomplete(...)` initialization, otherwise the autocomplete will handle the event and it won't work.